# Java 8 streams - restructure entity classes for UI Grid

Tags: java, hash-map

I have the following domain model:

> ```
> class Holding
> ------------
> Account account;
> DataSourceProduct dataSourceProduct;
>
> class Account
> -------------
> String name;
>
> class DataSourceProduct
> -------------
> DataSource dataSource;
> Product product;
> // other product data specific to the data source
>
> class Product
> --------------
> String id;    
>
> class DataSource
> ----------------
> String name;
> ```

I get a list of `Holding` data from three different data sources. I need to show the data in a grid. Each row in the grid has the same product and account and will have columns to show the product data as provided by the three different data sources. Note: One of the data sources may have a holding with a product id of `null`.

To accomplish this, I currently break up the list of holdings into several lists where each list contains only holdings with the same product id and account. Also, I key each list by data source. So, in the end, I have the following:

```
List<Map<DataSource,Holding>>
```

So, we have something like this:

```
index 0 in the list
    Map:Key       Map:Value
    datasource1   holding1AccordingToDs1  ----|
    datasource2   holding1AccordingToDs2  ----|---> all three holdings have same product and account
    datasource3   holding2AccordingToDs3  ----|
index 1 in the list
    Map:Key       Map:Value
    datasource1   holding2AccordingToDs1  ----|
    datasource2   holding2AccordingToDs2  ----|---> all three holdings have same product and account
index 2 in the list
    Map:Key       Map:Value
    datasource1   holding3AccordingToDs1  ----|
    datasource3   holding3AccordingToDs3  ----|---> all three holdings have
```

To get from `List<Holding>` to `List<Map<DataSource,Holding>>` I do the following:

```java
    // these holdings could have an null instrument id
    // and this data is returned from a different db than other
    // holdings
    List<Holding> aSourceHoldings = holdingService.getHoldings(date);

    List<Holding> unMatchedHoldings = aSourceHoldings .stream()
            .filter(h -> h.getDataSourceProduct().getProduct().getId() == null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // if null product id, no way to match to other instruments
    aSourceHoldings.removeAll(unMatchedHoldings);

    // get other data source holdings
    List<Holding> toBeMatchedHoldings = holdingRepository.getHoldings(date);
    toBeMatchedHoldings.addAll(aSourceHoldings);

    // grouping by account and product
    Map<Account, Map<Product, List<Holding>>> matchedHoldings = 
            toBeMatchedHoldings.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Holding::getAccount,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(h -> h.getDataSourceProduct().getProduct())));

List<Map<DataSource, Holding>> unifiedHoldings = new ArrayList<Map<DataSource, Holding>>();
    Map<DataSource, Holding> tmp = new HashMap<DataSource, Holding>();
    for (Map<Product, List<Holding>> productHoldings : matchedHoldings.values()) {
        for (List<Holding> holdings : productHoldings.values()) {
            for (Holding holding : holdings) {
                tempMap.put(holding.getDataSourceProduct.getDataSource(), holding);
             }
            unifiedHoldings.add(tempMap);
        }
    }
    return unifiedHoldings;
```

Like data sources, the number of accounts is small (4-5) and will remain fairly static over the years. Is it possible to reduce the number of manipulations to group and get the data that I need for the UI grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Type inference for generic instance creation

You can rely on [type inference for generic instance creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) when declaring `unifiedHoldings`:

```
List<Map<DataSource, List<Holding>>> unifiedHoldings = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### Mutable operations on collections

```
List<Holding> aSourceHoldings = holdingService.getHoldings(date);
List<Holding> unMatchedHoldings = /* ... */ ;
aSourceHoldings.removeAll(unMatchedHoldings);
List<Holding> toBeMatchedHoldings = holdingRepository.getHoldings(date);
toBeMatchedHoldings.addAll(aSourceHoldings);
```

Calling mutable operations such as `removeAll(Collection)` and `addAll(Collection)` may throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if the underlying `List` does not return a mutable implementation. As such, in these scenarios, you should be creating your own `List` given the resulting elements, and then do the necessary removal/addition calls on the new instance.

#### `Account` and `Product` usage

Interestingly, it looks like `Account` and `Product` themselves aren't used in the processing, after kind of using them as 'keys' for grouping. The nested `Map`s looks too peculiar, which brings us to the next point...

#### Grouping your `Holding` objects

> I currently break up the list of holdings into several lists where each list contains only holdings *with the same product id and account*. Also, I *key each list by data source*.
>
> (*emphasis mine*)

This looks like a good use case for a supplementary 'key' class that will allow us to grouping `Holding` objects with the same *account, product and data source*. For example:

```
private static final class HoldingKey {
    private final Account account;
    private final Product product;

    HoldingKey(Account account, Product product) {
        this.account = Objects.requireNonNull(account);
        this.product = Objects.requireNonNull(product);
    }

    Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof HoldingKey
                && getAccount().equals(((HoldingKey) o).getAccount())
                && getProduct().equals(((HoldingKey) o).getProduct());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getAccount(), getProduct());
    }

    static HoldingKey toKey(Holding holding) {
        return new HoldingKey(holding.getAccount(), 
                                holding.getDataSourceProduct().getProduct());
    }
}
```

Using the [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) `HoldingKey::toKey` to *group* `Holding` objects by, with a dash of [`Stream.concat(Stream, Stream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) to combine two streams together, we can combine the processing on both the repository and service results with relative ease:

```
    Stream<Holding> fromRepository = holdingRepository.getHoldings(date).stream();
    Stream<Holding> fromService = holdingService.getHoldings(date).stream()
            .filter(h -> h.getDataSourceProduct().getProduct().getId() != null);
    Map<HoldingKey, List<Holding>> map = Stream.concat(fromRepository, fromService)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(HoldingKey::toKey));
```

This simplifies the nested `Map`s we have by flattening that multi-key structure into a single `HoldingKey` object. Achieving what you require is a simple continuation on `map`'s `entrySet()`, with a mapping function to turn `List<Holding>` into your required `Map<DataSource, Holding>`:

```
private static final Function<List<Holding>, Map<DataSource, Holding>> MAPPER =
        x -> x.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                y -> y.getDataSourceProduct().getDataSource(), Function.identity()));

private static List<Map<DataSource, List<Holding>>> getUnifiedHoldings(Date date) {
    Stream<Holding> fromRepository = holdingRepository.getHoldings(date).stream();
    Stream<Holding> fromService = holdingService.getHoldings(date).stream()
            .filter(h -> h.getDataSourceProduct().getProduct().getId() != null);
    return Stream.concat(fromRepository, fromService)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(HoldingKey::toKey))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(MAPPER.compose(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here, we [`compose()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#compose-java.util.function.Function-) our `MAPPER` function with the 'extractor' function `Map.Entry::getValue` to derive our resulting list elements.

Comment: Awesome! +1 Thanks for spending the time to provide a lot detail and cover multiple points. I might be looking at this wrong, but I think the `HoldingKey` needs to be formed by using `Account` and `Product` (rather than `DataSourceProduct`). Then I suppose we don't have as easy access to `DataSource` in the `getDataSource()` method of `HoldingKey`.

Comment: After running a few tests, I realize that I have something wrong in the OP. Very sorry about this... but I actually need `getUnifiedHoldings to return a `List<Map<DataSource, Holding>>`. I have revised the OP. I think everything you answered still applies except for the last two operations in the return statement for `getUnifiedHoldings` and its return type. Sorry again and thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @James updated my answer.